# Table mis-labelled in text

Tags: tables

My table is written as such:

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\small\normalsize
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
    \caption[]{Upper limit intensities of missing $E2$ transitions in $^{78}$Ge. ``*" indicates the transition intensity is inflated by contamination in spectra from the 976.5 keV transition in the $^{76}$Ge beam.}  
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\noalign{\vskip 1mm} 
\hline
\hline
$E_{\textit{i }lev}$ & $E_\gamma$ & $E_{\textit{f }lev}$ & Relative Intensity & $\%$ Branching ratio \\
(keV) & (keV)&(keV)& upper limit& upper limit\\
\hline
3295 & 976* & 2319 & 2.5 & 7.4\\
2760& 1116 & 1644 & 0.1&0.3\\
2760& 1190 & 1570 & 0.6 &2.2\\
2319 & 1700 & 619 & 0.1 &0.2\\
2319& 1134 & 1186 & 0.6& 1.1\\
2319& 749 & 1570 &0.6 &1.1\\
\hline \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \label{table:upper limit}
\end{table}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\small\normalsize
```

In the text it should be Table 6.3 but when I compile, it returns as table 6.11 (the section of my chapter).
Help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ. Out of sheer curiosity: What are the two instances of `\small\normalsize` supposed to achieve?

Comment: Place the `\label` inside the `center` environment, for example immediately after the `\caption`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That works, but `center` should be avoided in that context, preferring the bare `\centering`.

Answer (score 1):

Two main suggestions:

- Don't use a `center` environment inside the `table` environment. Instead, use a simple `\centering` instruction.
- Be sure to place the `\caption` instruction before the `\label` instruction.

Adhering to these suggestions should suffice to generate correct cross-references to the tables in question.

Some additional suggestions, aimed at making the typeset table more readable (and the underlying LaTeX code more legible):

- Load the `booktabs` package to draw well-spaced horizontal rules; omit all vertical rules.
- Load the `threeparttable` package and employ `\tnote` directives and a `tablenotes` environment to typeset the footnote marker and the footnote text. Don't overload the caption with material that's meant to be placed in a table footnote.
- Learn to use the `setspace` package; that way, you don't have to fiddle with line spacing directives before and after `table` and `figure` environments.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} % or some other document class with "\chapter" macro
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{2.0} % don't modify the low-level macro "\baselinestretch" directly
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule directives
\usepackage{siunitx} % for "\si" and "\SI" macros
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{6}  % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{11}
\setcounter{table}{2}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption[]{Upper limit intensities of missing $E2$ transitions in $^{78}$Ge}
\label{table:upper limit}

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
$E_{i,\mathrm{lev}}$ & $E_{\gamma}$ & $E_{f,\mathrm{lev}}$ 
& Relative Intensity & \% Branching ratio \\
(\si{\kilo\electronvolt}) & (\si{\kilo\electronvolt})
& (\si{\kilo\electronvolt}) & upper limit& upper limit \\
\midrule
3295 & \phantom{0}976\tnote{*} & 2319 & 2.5 & 7.4\\
2760& 1116 & 1644 & 0.1&0.3\\
2760& 1190 & 1570 & 0.6 &2.2\\
2319 & 1700 & \phantom{0}619 & 0.1 &0.2\\
2319& 1134 & 1186 & 0.6& 1.1\\
2319& \phantom{0}749 & 1570 &0.6 &1.1\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item[*]indicates the transition intensity is inflated by contamination in spectra 
from the \SI{976.5}{\kilo\electronvolt} transition in the $^{76}$Ge beam.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

A cross-reference to Table \ref{table:upper limit}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Additional question--so many of my captions are much longer than this one.. and this new environment makes it only as wide as the table. How do I use the page width for the caption?

Comment: @RadioactiveAnnie - In my view, table and figure captions should be short and snappy. Their main purpose is to inform readers quickly what the table or figure is about. If you have very long captions, I would have to guess that a good chunk of the "caption" isn't so much a "real caption" but, rather, some auxiliary or subsidiary material. Consider moving such material out of the caption and placing it between the `\end{threeparttable}` and `\end{table}` directives.